# Why does ADL not work with an unnamed initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider the following code. Here, if we use `std::begin` on an unnamed `initializer_list` with explicit `std::`, it works OK. If we omit the `std::` and use `begin` on a named `initializer_list`, it also works fine. But if we omit `std::` and do the rest similarly to the first case, it fails to compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
void func(int len, const int* x)
{
    for(int i=0;i<len;++i)
        std::cout << x[i] << "\n";
}
int main()
{
    {
        // OK
        func(5, std::begin({1,3,6,823,-35}));
    }
    {
        // OK
        auto&& list = {1,3,6,823,-35};
        func(5, begin(list));
    }
//  {
//      // Fails to compile
//      func(5, begin({1,3,6,823,-35}));
//  }
}
```

I get the following compilation error (after I uncomment the faulty code):

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:21:11: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
   func(5, begin({1,3,6,823,-35}));
           ^~~~~
test.cpp:21:11: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/string:51,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iostream:39,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/range_access.h:105:37: note:   ‘std::begin’
   template<typename _Tp> const _Tp* begin(const valarray<_Tp>&);
                                     ^~~~~
```

Why does ADL work with a named `initializer_list` (i.e. `list` in the example above) but fail with an unnamed one?

Comment: Because `{1,3,6,823,-35}` is not an `std::initializer_list`, it isn't even an expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but fail with an unnamed one?

No, `{1,3,6,823,-35}` is not an unnamed `std::initializer_list`. `{1,3,6,823,-35}` is a [braced-init-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Notes). Even it could be used to construct an `std::initializer_list` in specified contexts but it's not `std::initializer_list` itself. Then ADL won't work for `begin({1,3,6,823,-35})`.

> A braced-init-list is not an expression and therefore has no type, e.g. `decltype({1,2})` is ill-formed.

and

> A special exception is made for type deduction using the keyword `auto` , which deduces any braced-init-list as `std::initializer_list`.

That's why the 2nd case works; `list` is deudced as `std::initializer_list&&`.